# style asp textbox with css 3 how to declare input properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, textbox

I'm developing an asp web form and I found a tutorial online on expanding the selected textbox, it is only working with textarea but not with `asp:textbox`

here is the declaration I want to make it work with `asp:textbox`

```
.form1 input, .form1 textarea 
    -moz-transition: padding .25s;
    -webkit-transition: padding .25s;
    -o-transition: padding .25s;
    transition: padding .25s;
}
```

Comment: Most browsers have developer tools (i.e. in IE - F12) - just look at generated elements and see types/classes to write correct selectors.

Comment: Give a class to your textbox and try adding it to your CSS

Answer (score 0):

Random guess (no HTML/ASPX given): you don't have parent element with class "form1" on the page, so `INPUT` (single line `asp:textbox`) or `TEXTAREA` (multiline `asp:textbox`) elements do not pick your CSS.